# How to Avoid Killed:9 message

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I have a list with length 37500 in my code. However, when I try to assign that list to a dictionary slot, I get the VSCode error, Killed:9. Is there any way to avoid this? Here is my code:

```
#The testing image naturally has a grey linein the middle



from PIL import Image, ImageOps
import numpy as np
from pathlib import Path
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pickle
import time
import os

mod_path = Path(__file__).parent

input_dirImage = os.listdir((mod_path / "Images").resolve())
imput_dirGround = os.listdir((mod_path / "groundTruth").resolve())
len_images = len(input_dirImage)
size = (650,650) #Size of the ROI
fitSize = (900,800) #Size to change the original Image to before ROI
start_time = time.time() #starting the timer

ROIList = [] #Array that holds the ROI grayscale values
covidList = [] #Whether the ROI is covid positive or negative
groundList = [] #Array that holds the ROI groundtruth true or false values



for image in input_dirImage[0:len_images]:
if image == '.DS_Store':
    continue

parent_path = Path(__file__).parent

secondDirImage = (mod_path / "Images" / image).resolve() #Path of the covid image
secondDirGround = groundTruthDir = (mod_path / "groundTruth" / "fourPositive_b&w.tif").resolve() #Path of the ground truth

image = Image.open(str(secondDirImage))
ground = Image.open(str(secondDirGround))

image = ImageOps.fit(image, fitSize, Image.ANTIALIAS)
ground = ImageOps.fit(ground, fitSize, Image.ANTIALIAS)


xBias = 0
yBias = 0

while(yBias + size[1] <= fitSize[1]):
    crop_rectangle = (xBias, yBias, xBias + size[0], yBias + size[1])

    ROIList.append(np.mean(np.array(image.crop(crop_rectangle)),axis = 2))

    tempGround  = np.mean(np.array(ground.crop(crop_rectangle)),axis = 2)
    count = 0
    # print(tempGround.size)
    # print(np.array(ground.crop(crop_rectangle)).shape)
    # print(np.mean(np.array(ground.crop(crop_rectangle)),axis = 2).shape)
    # for i in range(0,tempGround.shape[0]):
    #     for j in range(0,tempGround.shape[1]):
    #         if tempGround[i][j] > 50:
    #             count+=1
    # print(count)
    tempGround[tempGround<50.0] = False
    tempGround[tempGround>240.0] = True  #All values greater than 240 become true. Are in this order because otherwise
    

    # print(np.count_nonzero(tempGround))
    groundList.append(tempGround)

    # plt.imshow(np.mean(image.crop(crop_rectangle),axis = 2),cmap = "gray", vmin = 0, vmax = 255)
    # plt.show(block = False)
    # plt.pause(.2)
    # plt.close()
    # plt.imshow(np.mean(ground.crop(crop_rectangle),axis = 2),cmap = "gray", vmin = 0, vmax = 255)
    # plt.show(block = False)
    # plt.pause(.2)
    # plt.close()


    if(xBias + size[0] == fitSize[0]): #Only need to check the image's status, as the image and the ground have the same dimensions
        yBias += 1
        xBias = 0
        print("dang")
    else:
        xBias +=1

dictionary = dict()
dictionary['image'] = ROIList
dictionary['ground'] = groundList

print("yo")
print(np.count_nonzero(dictionary['ground']))
print(len(dictionary['ground']))

plt.imshow(dictionary['image'][105], cmap = "gray", vmin = 0, vmax = 255)
plt.show()
plt.imshow(dictionary['ground'][105], cmap = "gray", vmin = 0, vmax = 1)
plt.show()
plt.imshow(dictionary['image'][200], cmap = "gray", vmin = 0, vmax = 255)
plt.show()
plt.imshow(dictionary['ground'][200], cmap = "gray", vmin = 0, vmax = 1)
plt.show()
plt.imshow(dictionary['image'][205], cmap = "gray", vmin = 0, vmax = 255)
plt.show()
plt.imshow(dictionary['ground'][205], cmap = "gray", vmin = 0, vmax = 1)
plt.show()
plt.imshow(dictionary['image'][150], cmap = "gray", vmin = 0, vmax = 255)
plt.show()
plt.imshow(dictionary['ground'][150], cmap = "gray", vmin = 0, vmax = 1)
plt.show()
with open((mod_path / 'imageOne.pickle').resolve(),'wb') as handle:
        pickle.dump(dictionary, handle, protocol = pickle.HIGHEST_PROTOCOL)
    



print("Process finished --- %s seconds ---" % (time.time() - start_time))
```

I understand this error message is result of a lack of memory, would assigning the data to the dictionary gradually help this at all?

Comment: try code without VSCode t see if problem is Python or VSCode. VSCode is only IDE/Editor and you need it only to write code but not to run it.

Comment: @furas I just did, it still shows the same error on terminal